# How to .click() on a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently working with selenium chromedriver in python and I want to collapse this open.

```py
<a id="pp-T0-81" href="javascript:void(0)" data-action="a-expander-toggle" class="a-expander-header a-declarative a-expander-inline-header pmts-apply-claim-code a-spacing-base a-link-expander" data-a-expander-toggle="{&quot;allowLinkDefault&quot;:true, &quot;expand_prompt&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;collapse_prompt&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"><i class="a-icon a-icon-collapse"></i><span class="a-expander-prompt"><span class="a-size-base xh-highlight">Voer een cadeaubon- of promotiecode in.</span></span></a>
```

However the `id="pp-T0-81"` seems to change when the page is refreshed.

Not very experienced but I tried to use `Xpath` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what XPath makes sense in your scenario, but if you think `data-action` and `class` are unique and will stay stable (you say that `id` kept changing), then you could use those two:

```js
const paragraphCount = document.evaluate( `//a[@data-action='a-expander-toggle'][@class='a-expander-header a-declarative a-expander-inline-header pmts-apply-claim-code a-spacing-base a-link-expander']`, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue

console.log(paragraphCount)
```

```html
<a id="pp-T0-81" href="javascript:void(0)" data-action="a-expander-toggle" class="a-expander-header a-declarative a-expander-inline-header pmts-apply-claim-code a-spacing-base a-link-expander" data-a-expander-toggle="{&quot;allowLinkDefault&quot;:true, &quot;expand_prompt&quot;:&quot;&quot;, &quot;collapse_prompt&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"><i class="a-icon a-icon-collapse"></i><span class="a-expander-prompt"><span class="a-size-base xh-highlight">Voer een cadeaubon- of promotiecode in.</span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic id's for testing isn't really a reliable idea. I'd suggest using DOM nesting to target the element.